# json responce is Multiple Array How i can Parse it using Volley

Tags: json, request, android-volley, android, gson

How to Show "Category" , according to Category "Title", & "Price"
in RecyclerView One Row.
   my Api url is   https://www.paidup.io/api/v1/businesses/212/menu

This Url returns response like:

```
  [{
                  "category": "Espresso & Coffee",
                  "items": [{
                    "title": "Vacuum Coffee",
                    "size": [{
                         "label": "medium",
                         "price": 125
                    }, {
                    "label": "large",
                    "price": 145
                 }]
             }, {
                 "title": "Cafe Latte",
                 "size": [{
                    "label": "small",
                    "price": 115
                }, {
                    "label": "medium",
                    "price": 135
                }, {
                    "label": "large",
                    "price": 150
               }]
            }, {
                "title": "Cafe Mocha",
                "size": [{
                    "label": "small",
                    "price": 115
                }, {
                    "label": "medium",
                    "price": 135
                }, {
                    "label": "large",
                    "price": 150
                }]
             }, {
                "title": "White Mocha",
                "size": [{
                    "label": "small",
                    "price": 120
                }, {
                    "label": "medium",
                    "price": 145
                 }, {
                    "label": "large",
                     "price": 155
                }]
            }, {
                "title": "Caramel Macchiato",
                "size": [{
                    "label": "small",
                    "price": 125
                }, {
                    "label": "medium",
                    "price": 145
                 }, {
                    "label": "large",
                    "price": 165
                }]
            }, {
                "title": "Coffee De Leche",
                 "size": [{
                    "label": "small",
                    "price": 130
                }, {
                    "label": "medium",
                     "price": 145
                }, {
                "label": "large",
                    "price": 160
                }]
            }, {
                "title": "Cafe-UK Coffee Lava",
                "size": null,
                "price": 145
            }]
        }, {
            "category": "Frappe",
            "items": [{
                 "title": "Coffee Base",
                 "size": [{
                    "label": "small",
                    "price": 140
                }, {
                    "label": "medium",
                    "price": 155
               }, {
                    "label": "large",
                    "price": 170
                }]
            }, {
                "title": "Milk Base",
                "size": [{
                    "label": "small",
                    "price": 130
                }, {
                    "label": "medium",
                    "price": 145
                }, {
                    "label": "large",
                    "price": 160
                 }]
             }, {
                "title": "Cream Soda Float w\/Ice-cream",
                "size": null,
                "price": 140
            }]
         }, {
            "category": "Milk Tea & Juice",
            "items": [{
                "title": "Milk Tea",
                "size": [{
                    "label": "small",
                    "price": 105
                }, {
                    "label": "medium",
                    "price": 120
                }]
             }, {
                "title": "Hot Tea",
                "size": null,
                "price": 120
             }, {
                "title": "Italian Soda",
                "size": [{
                    "label": "small",
                    "price": 105
                }, {
                    "label": "medium",
                    "price": 120
                }, {
                    "label": "large",
                    "price": 140
                }]
            }, {
                 "title": "Juice",
                 "size": null,
                 "price": 105
            }]
          }, {
            "category": "Food",
            "items": [{
                "title": "Ultimate Chili Con Fries",
                "size": null,
                "price": 290
            }, {
                "title": "Nachos",
                "size": null,
                "price": 290
             }, {
                "title": "Marble Potato Fondue",
                "size": null,
                "price": 120
             }, {
                 "title":"Breakfast",
                 "size":null,
                 "price":220
             }]}]
```

and my POJO Classes are Like:

```
package ph.paidup.models;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by oxiloindia on 3/30/2016.
 */
 public class Item {

     @SerializedName("title")
     @Expose
     private String title;
     @SerializedName("size")
     @Expose
     private Object size;
     @SerializedName("price")
     @Expose
     private Integer price;

     /**
      *
      * @return
      * The title
      */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
     }

      /**
      *
     * @param title
     * The title
      */
     public void setTitle(String title) {
         this.title = title;
    }

     /**
      *
      * @return
      * The size
      */
      public Object getSize() {
          return size;
     }

      /**
      *
     * @param size
     * The size
     */
     public void setSize(Object size) {
         this.size = size;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
    * The price
     */
     public Integer getPrice() {
         return price;
     }

     /**
      *
      * @param price
      * The price
       */
     public void setPrice(Integer price) {
         this.price = price;
     }
 }
```

and another class:

```
package ph.paidup.models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
  * Created by oxiloindia on 3/30/2016.
 */
 @Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
 public class MenuRequest {

    @SerializedName("category")
    @Expose
    private String category;
    @SerializedName("items")
    @Expose
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    /**
     *
      * @return
     * The category
     */
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param category
     * The category
     */
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The items
     */
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param items
     * The items
     */
    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Now i want to parse this in my Activity to Get
According to 
"category" ,  needs its
"title"  and
"price"  in recyclerview

i am Trying to do it Like this way:

```
 public void getInVoice() {
    showProgress(true);
    String  URL="https://www.paidup.io/api/v1/businesses/212/menu";

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,URL,null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
         showProgress(false);
        VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                String desc = jsonObject.getString("category");
                JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                groupItem.items = (List<Item>) jsonParser.parse(String.valueOf(response));

                // Create a new adapter with  data items
                mExpandableAdapter = new BakeryMenuExpandableAdapter(getActivity(), setUpList(groupItem.items)) {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {

                    }
                };
                // Attach this activity to the Adapter as the ExpandCollapseListener
                mExpandableAdapter.setExpandCollapseListener(new ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ExpandCollapseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onListItemExpanded(int position) {
                        Log.e("CHEEE", "" + position);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onListItemCollapsed(int position) {

                    }
                });

                // Set the RecyclerView's adapter to the ExpandableAdapter we just created
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mExpandableAdapter);
                // Set the layout manager to a LinearLayout manager for vertical list
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + response + "\"");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null && isAdded())
            showProgress(false);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong. please try it again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

// add the request object to the queue to be executed
addToRequestQueue(req, TAG);
}
```

I tried all Requests to Parse it but couldn't get success.

What should i need to do in Try block to get List of Items for recyclerview

thanks in advance....plz solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in your response callback.

1) You use JsonRequest of volley but you actually want to parse it into a POJO with Gson.

2) you get array of menurequest objects but it seems you handle then as just one MenuRequest

so you don't really need those:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                String desc = jsonObject.getString("category");
                JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                groupItem.items = (List<Item>) jsonParser.parse(String.valueOf(response));
```

These actually throws different exceptions.

instead you can do:

```
  MenuRequest[] items = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), MenuRequest[].class);
```

so in items you will endup with an Array of MenuRequest objects

then you can do whatever you need for example:

```
for(MenuRequest item:items) {
                            Log.d("test", "item: " +item);
                        }
```